# library not found for -lObjectiveChipmunk

Tags: ios, chipmunk

How to solve such type of error?

ld: library not found for -lObjectiveChipmunk
[image: Header search path setting]
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because probably your library search path might not be correct. Either you can give the right path there or can have `./**` as a path